# Nodejs - login system has error check email

Tags: node.js, authentication, node-modules, system, nodemon

Hello i'm trying to create login system in node js and when i testing code i have problem: "email not found". What's wrong?

UserModel:
`

```
const Users = db.define('logindata',{
    mail: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    isactive: {
        type: DataTypes.NUMBER
    },
    refresh_token: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
    }

},{

    freezeTableName:true

});
```

`

UserControl.js:
`

```
export const Login = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await Users.findAll({
            where:{
                mail: req.body.mail,
            }
        });
        const match = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password);
        if(!match) return res.status(400).json({msg: "wrong password"});
        const userId = user[0].id;
        const mail = user[0].mail;
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({userId, mail}, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,{
            expiresIn: '20s'
            
        });
        const refreshToken = jwt.sign({userId, mail}, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,{
            expiresIn: '1d'
        });
        
        await Users.update({refresh_token: refreshToken},{
            where: {
                id: userId
            }
        });
        res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken,{
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
            secure: true
        });
        res.json({accessToken});
    } 
    catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({msg:"email not found"});
    }
```

`

e-mail and password are checked correctly but still i have error

Comment: Add `console.log(error)` and see what error do you get

Comment: It can be anything, you should print the error with a `console.error` that you will keep My guess is that you don't find the user and in `bcrypt.compare`, you do `user[0].password` with user undefined, so it throw

Comment: If there only was an `error` variable, which could tell you, what the actual error is ...

Comment: 'Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
    at module.exports [as sign] (C:\xampp\htdocs\CMMS\clms\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:107:20)
    at Login (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/CMMS/clms/backend/controllers/Users.js:45:33)'

Comment: depending on what line 45 in your user.js file is, either `ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET` or `REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET` (or both) doesn't have a value ..